# What does the term 'a uniform RVB spin-liquid state' mean?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, terminology

I encountered this term **a uniform RVB spin-liquid state** in some [articles](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v65/i16/e165113), for example, see the paragraph under Eq.(29) on page 9 in this [paper](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v65/i16/e165113).

What does the word '*uniform* ' mean? Simply from the mean-field anzats(see Eq.(28)), how to see that the projected spin wave-function is a RVB state which is a superposition of spin-singlet states? And is the low-energy gauge structure of **a uniform RVB spin-liquid state** always $SU(2)$?

Thank you very much.